# How do I understand how top sites and web apps actually function underneath the hood?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, web, stack

I'd like to get into web application development, but I'm pretty much a novice. How do I even begin to guess/understand how sites such as Twitter or say, HipMunk, might work in the first place, top to bottom?

This link does an excellent job of Quora's underlying technology: http://www.philwhln.com/quoras-technology-examined

Any links or pointers that I could use would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:  http://highscalability.com/

Specifically, browse [this](http://highscalability.com/blog/category/example) section for real-life examples of architecture of highly loaded web-sites.